# macdeployqt not deploying QtQuick modules

Tags: qt, qml, macdeployqt

I'm using *macdeployqt* to deploy one QML application to Mac OS and when I finish, with all paths fine and try to execute it from .dmg generated package I can start application. Trying to execute it from term I get a QML error that says QtQuick.Window and other modules are not installed. Any clue about?

This is the command that I have tried:

```
$ macdeployqt MyApp.app -qmldir=/Users/jgd/dev/myapp -no-strip
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Log: Deploying QML imports
Log: Application QML file search path(s) is ("/Users/jngd/devel/MyApp/")
ERROR: qmlimportscanner output error. Expected json array, got:
ERROR: ""
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("/Users/jngd/devel/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/qmlimportscanner") is still running.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete command you used.

Comment: @Mitch Edition done.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe include the output as well? https://github.com/qt/qttools/blob/5.10/src/macdeployqt/macdeployqt/main.cpp#L41 says there is a -verbose option, so that might give you some clues as well.

Comment: I don't know how Mac OS works but at other OS this might mean version conflict ie. maybe there are more then one Qt packages installed on the same machine.